# Where to find the callsigns of the en route controllers?

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-planning, datasets, call-sign

I am looking for the callsigns of ATC [upper information region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_information_region) (UIR) controllers on a flight from Frankfurt EDDF to Seattle KSEA. According to the flight plan, the UIRs crossed are:

- EDDV (Hannover)
- EHAA (Amsterdam)
- EGTT (London)
- EGPX (Scottish)
- EGGX (Shanwick)
- BIRD (Reykjavik)
- CZEG (Edmonton)
- CZVR (Vancouver) and
- KZSE (Seattle).

First, where can I find charts and information on the sectors within a UIR?

Second, does each sector have a different callsign, or are callsigns coupled to the UIR? For example, EGPX Shanwick will probably have multiple sectors, will the callsign be always Shanwick control? If they are UIR-dependent, what are the callsigns of the above-mentioned UIRs?

Answer (score 1):

You can look in each country's AIP, specifically section ENR 2.1. Below is for [the Netherlands](http://www.ais-netherlands.nl/):

[image]

Note the name/call-sign 'Maastricht Radar' for at or above FL 245. [Maastricht UAC](https://www.eurocontrol.int/muac) is...

> ... an international non-profit air navigation service provider, operated by EUROCONTROL on behalf of four States – Belgium, Germany, Luxembourg and the Netherlands.

Also from the AIP's you can find the division of the FIR's, example:

[image]